# Read a custom xml file in a cron

Tags: magento2, cron

I just create a custom module on Magento 2.0.7.
I have a block that reads a custom folder
Example:

```
$files = scandir('_product_updates');
```

And everything works.
Now, I create a cron, that should read the same folder. I have the same code there:

```
$files = scandir('_product_updates');
```

But the cron is throwing an exception :

> 'ErrorException' with message 'scandir('_product_updates'): failed to
>   open dir: No such file or directory

Why, I can read like this on a block, but not in a cron?

My module structure:

[image]

The folder with files, that I want to read is outside the module, in the same level that app folder.

Any clue?

Comment: You can show us the folder structure?

Comment: Can you take the screen shot your module structure?

Comment: yes:                                                                                                                                    -_product_update                                                                                                             - app  > code > Tool > ImportExportTool > Cron

Comment: You can take the picture and update your question with the image?

Comment: How about your issue?

Answer (score 0):

1) We can use `BP` constant from `app/autoload.php`.

```
$folderPath = BP . '_product_updates';
$files = scandir($folderPath);
```

2) We can use `Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList` to get absolute path.

```
protected directory_list;

public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList $directory_list
) {
        $this->directory_list = $directory_list;  
}

......

$this->directory_list->getPath('_product_updates');
```